# Derivative of squared form

Tags: matrices, derivatives, symmetric-matrices

Let $\boldsymbol{Y}$ be a matrix with dimension $2 \times n$, $\boldsymbol{X}_c$ and $\boldsymbol{X}_r$ are matrices $n \times p$, $\Sigma$ is a nonsingular and symmetric matrix $2 \times 2$, $\beta_c = (\beta_{c1}, \ldots, \beta_{cp})^T$ and $\beta_r = (\beta_{r1}, \ldots, \beta_{rp})^T$.

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{u}_i =\{\boldsymbol{Y}_i - [\boldsymbol{X}_{ci}\beta_c, g^{-1}(\boldsymbol{X}_{ri}\beta_r)]^T\}^T \Sigma^{-1}\{\boldsymbol{Y}_i - [\boldsymbol{X}_{ci}\beta_c, g^{-1}(\boldsymbol{X}_{ri}\beta_r)]^T\}, i = 1, \ldots, n.
\end{equation}

I'd like to calculate $\partial \boldsymbol{u}_i / \partial \boldsymbol{\beta}_r$. But, I cannot solve the differentiation with the $g^{-1}(\cdot)$ function.

Comment: You have a dimension mismatch
$$\eqalign{
Y_i &\in {\mathbb R}^{2\times 1}\quad\ne\quad
\pmatrix{X_c\beta_c&X_r\beta_r}^T &\in {\mathbb R}^{2\times n} \cr
}$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the index $i$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you know how to calculate the derivative of the inverse function, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
h(z)=g^{-1}(z) \implies\frac{dh}{dz}= h'(z) \cr
}$$
Define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
e_k &\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times 1},\quad
\varepsilon_k \in {\mathbb R}^{2\times 1}&{\rm (standard\,basis)} \cr
z_k &= e_k^TX_r\beta_r,\quad p_k = h(z_k),\quad q_k = h'(z_k)&\in{\mathbb R}^{1}\cr
w_k &= \pmatrix{e_k^TX_c\beta_c\\p_k} - \pmatrix{\varepsilon_1^TY_k\\\varepsilon_2^TY_k}&\in{\mathbb R}^{2\times 1} \cr
&= \big(e_k^TX_c\beta_c-\varepsilon_1^TY_k\big)\varepsilon_1 + \big(p_k-\varepsilon_2^TY_k\big)\varepsilon_2 \cr
dw_k &= \varepsilon_2\,dp_k = \varepsilon_2q_k\,dz_k \cr
}$$
Write the $u_k$ vectors in terms of these new vectors. Then find the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
u_k &= w_k^T\Sigma^{-1}w_k = \Sigma^{-1}:w_kw_k^T \cr
du_k &= 2\Sigma^{-1}w_k:dw_k \cr
 &= 2\Sigma^{-1}w_k:\varepsilon_2\,q_k\,dz_k \cr
 &= \Big(2\varepsilon_2^T\Sigma^{-1}w_k\Big)q_k\Big(e_k^TX_r\,d\beta_r\Big) \cr
\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial\beta_r}
 &= \Big(2\varepsilon_2^T\Sigma^{-1}w_k\Big)q_k\Big(X_r^Te_k\Big) \cr
 &= \Big(2\varepsilon_2^T\Sigma^{-1}w_k\Big)\,X_r^TQe_k \cr
}$$
where the matrix $\,Q={\rm Diag}(q_k)\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$

In some intermediate steps, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)}$$